# How to re-arrange payment options in the payment checkout page?

Tags: commerce

I have several payment options i have enabled in Drupal Commerce. But I do not know how to arrange them in a certain order on the payment checkout page.

I have tried looking out for ways to do this, but failed.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1047546